# How to run a 10-fold cross validation for a LASSO with pre selected Lambda

Tags: r, cross-validation, r-caret, glmnet, lasso-regression

I have chosen a lambda by running the LASSO multiple times and taking the mean lambda, I have used `glmnet`. I know want to run a 10-fold cross validation for this LASSO with this Lambda.

This is an example of the code I have tried so far:

```
library(caret)
library(glmnet)
```

```
train.control = trainControl(method = "cv", number = 10)


lm.out = lm(outcome ~ 0 +., data = df)
x = model.matrix(lm.out)
y = df$outcome

model = train(glmnet(x, y, lambda = mean(Lambda_LASSO)),
              data = df, trControl = train.control)
```

Here Lambda_LASSO is a vector of Lambdas taken out from iterative runs of cv.glmnet.

Comment: you do not need to run `lm` to be able to extract the model matrix `x = model.matrix(outcome ~ 0 +., data = df)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I have to say this sounds really odd:

> I have chosen a lambda by running the LASSO multiple times and taking
> the mean lambda

What would be the purpose of taking the mean of your lambda values?

Next time provide an example dataset, and also specify whether it's classification or regression. let's say your `df` is something like this and we get the lambdas from glmnet:

```
df = data.frame(matrix(runif(50*30),ncol=30))
df$outcome = rnorm(50)

x = model.matrix(outcome ~ 0 +., data = df)
y = df$outcome

Lambda_LASSO = glmnet(x,y)$lambda
```

You can feed it into caret using `tuneGrid =` and fix alpha at 1 since you are doing lasso:

```
train.control = trainControl(method = "cv", number = 10)

model = train(x=x,y=y,
tuneGrid = data.frame(alpha=1,lambda = mean(Lambda_LASSO)),
trControl = train.control,
method = "glmnet")


glmnet 

50 samples
30 predictors

No pre-processing
Resampling: Cross-Validated (10 fold) 
Summary of sample sizes: 43, 46, 46, 45, 46, 45, ... 
Resampling results:

  RMSE      Rsquared   MAE     
  1.519513  0.3486916  1.286363

Tuning parameter 'alpha' was held constant at a value of 1
Tuning
 parameter 'lambda' was held constant at a value of 0.03752899
```

Comment: Thanks, I was using 10-fold cross validation (the default) with glmnet. Therefore there is randomness in the way the data is split, and is some variance in how lambda is selected. So I have basically done repeated k-fold cross validation which I don't think is that strange.